# BeautifulSoup, I want to scrape the text exactly its real shape

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I´m trying to scrape a text from several pages, an example-page :< [https://www.centerwatch.com/directories/1067-fda-approved-drugs/listing/3092-afinitor-everolimus>](https://www.centerwatch.com/directories/1067-fda-approved-drugs/listing/3092-afinitor-everolimus%3E)

I do not need the headers, I only need the "p" tags that follows each "h2". The problem is that i could scrape if i use the "get_text()" function. But when i print it, it avoid "/br" and is not easy to read. What i want is that the page content be shown as it is on the page. Thank You!

pd: the code doesn´t work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import requests
import csv

link = requests.get('https://www.centerwatch.com/directories/1067-fda-approved-drugs/listing/3092-afinitor-everolimus')

soup = BeautifulSoup(link.content, 'lxml')
drugName = soup.find('div', class_='company-navigation').find('h1').text.strip()
gralInfo = soup.find('div', class_='body directory-listing-profile__description')
for h2 in gralInfo.find_all('h2'):
    for sibling in h2.find_next_siblings():
        if (sibling.name == 'h2'):
            break
        else:
            text = sibling.get_text()
            print(text)

    print()
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.get_text()` with `separator='\n'` is what you're looking for?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.centerwatch.com/directories/1067-fda-approved-drugs/listing/3092-afinitor-everolimus'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('.body').get_text(separator='\n'))  # you can put strip=True as well.
```

Prints:

```
General Information


Afinitor is an inhibitor of mTOR (mammalian target of rapamycin), a serine-threonine kinase, downstream of the PI3K/AKT pathway. The mTOR pathway is dysregulated in several human cancers. Everolimus binds to an intracellular protein, FKBP-12, resulting in an inhibitory complex formation and inhibition of mTOR kinase activity. Inhibition of mTOR by everolimus has been shown to reduce cell proliferation, angiogenesis, and glucose uptake in in vitro and/or in vivo studies.
Afinitor is specifically indicated for the treatment of  advanced renal cell carcinoma after failure of treatment with sunitinib or sorafenib.
Afinitor is supplied as a 5 mg or 10 mg tablet designed for oral administration. The recommended initial dose of the drug is 10 mg, to be taken once daily at the same time every day, either with or without food. Afinitor tablets should be swallowed whole with a glass of water; they should not be chewed or crushed.


Clinical Results


FDA Approval
FDA approval of Afinitor was based on the results of a clinical trial. This international, multicenter, randomized, double-blind study enrolled 416 subjects with metastatic renal cell carcinoma whose disease had progressed despite prior treatment with sunitinib, sorafenib, or both sequentially. The subjects received Afinitor 10 mg once daily or placebo, both in conjunction with best cupportive care. After 


...and so on.
```

Comment: You are awesome! I´m very grateful <3